# Constructing the limit of functions in $C[a,b]$ with maximum value norm

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Then prove that $C[a,b]$ along with the norm $$\|u\| \equiv \max_{a\leq x\leq b}|u(x)|$$ is a Banach space.

**Attempt:** Let $(u_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b] \implies \|u_n-u_m\|<\epsilon~\forall~n\geq N$. This means $$\max_x |u_n(x)-u_m(x)| < \epsilon~\forall~n\geq N$$

For each $x_0 \in [a,b]$, $$|u_n(x_0)-u_m(x_0)|<\epsilon~\forall~n\geq N$$

Define $y_n \equiv u_n(x_0)$. Then the real sequence $(y_n)$ is Cauchy. Since the set of real numbers over the real field is complete, $(y_n)$ converges (call the limit $y$). Now define $u(x_0) \equiv y$. Repeat the same procedure, replacing $x_0$ by all other remaining points in $[a,b]$. That way we would have constructed the function $u$ on $[a,b]$ whose values $u(x)$ are the limit points of sequences $(u_n(x))$. So

$$u_n(x) \to u(x)~~\forall~x \in [a,b]$$

which means $(u_n)$ is uniformly convergent. Is this approach correct or are there any subtleties that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You need that $u$ is continuous again. If you don't know already that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous again, that would require additional argument.

Comment: @JanBohr: So in the book I'm reading, while proving the same result, the author gets as far as proving that $u_n(x) \to u(x)$. Then he states, "By a classical result, this implies the continuity of the limit function $u:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$." By "classical result", does he mean what you said?

Comment: I guess that's what he meant. However, at a second look I noticed that you actually do not prove that the limit is uniform. This is definitely missing. (You only prove pointwise convergence!)

Comment: @JanBohr: But didn't I prove that given $\epsilon > 0$, $|u_n(x)-u(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$? That means uniform convergence as far as I know.

Comment: @JanBohr: Since $(u_n(x_0))$ converges, given $\epsilon > 0$, there's a $N_{x_0}$ such that $|u_n(x_0) - u(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N_{x_0}$. Similarly for all other $x \in [a,b]$. So $|u_n(x)-u(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq \max_{x \in [a,b]} N_x$. That's uniform convergence, right?